# Debian WSL shell printf: command not found

Tags: xml, bash, shell, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run a simple setup script that will create some files using the command printf.

The problem is that when I try to make the first lines of an xml file it throws me an error:

```
./setup.sh: line 460: ﻿printf: command not found
./setup.sh: line 583: ﻿printf: command not found
```

I can't understand why this is happening, maybe a character needs to be escaped, I input the same command in the shell and it doesn't give me an error.

Here's some code:

```
455 - # ----- Project file -----
456 -
457 - DestFile="${my_project_d}minivmac.vcxproj"
458 - printf "" > "${DestFile}"
459 - 
﻿460 - printf "%s\n" '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' >> "${DestFile}"
461 - printf "%s\n" '<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">' >> "${DestFile}"
462 - printf "%s\n" '   <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">' >> "${DestFile}"
463 - printf "%s\n" '       <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">' >> "${DestFile}"
464 - printf "%s\n" '           <Configuration>Release</Configuration>' >> "${DestFile}"
465 - printf "%s\n" '           <Platform>x64</Platform>' >> "${DestFile}"
466 - printf "%s\n" '       </ProjectConfiguration>' >> "${DestFile}"
467 - printf "%s\n" '   </ItemGroup>' >> "${DestFile}"
......................................................................
578 - # ----- Project Filters file -----
579 - 
580 - DestFile="${my_project_d}minivmac.vcxproj.filters"
581 - printf "" > "${DestFile}"
582 - 
583 - ﻿printf "%s\n" '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' >> "${DestFile}"
584 - printf "%s\n" '<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">' >> "${DestFile}"
585 - printf "%s\n" '   <ItemGroup>' >> "${DestFile}"
586 - printf "%s\n" '       <Filter Include="Header Files">' >> "${DestFile}"
587 - printf "%s\n" '           <UniqueIdentifier>{00030000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</UniqueIdentifier>' >> "${DestFile}"
588 - printf "%s\n" '           <Extensions>h;hpp;hxx;hm;inl;inc;xsd</Extensions>' >> "${DestFile}"
589 - printf "%s\n" '       </Filter>' >> "${DestFile}"
```

I'm running this code in the lastest Debian terminal of WSL

Comment: There's an (invisible) byte order mark character before those `printf` commands (right at the beginning of the line), and the shell is interpreting it as part of the command. Your editor may have a way to show weird characters so you can delete them directly, or you could just delete and retype the lines.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Just as you said there were three `non-printable` characters on there, so I opened the file with my hex editor and removed them, thanks for the help, BTW if you want to post your comment as a solution, I'll mark it as right.

Comment: `cat -v` can be used to show non-printing bytes/characters in a file.